# Add build step to team city - Unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

Can some one help with setting up a build step for running Unit tests in a TeamCity build configuration. I can currently run the unit test from VS Studio and they all run successfully. I need to add a new build step to an existing build configuration that runs these unit tests automatically. Currently I have no idea as to what needs to be picked as a runner type.. if I pick MSTest, what do I enter in so many fields that are available in Team City UI?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filling the "Edit assemblies include list" text box should be enough. Put paths to your test assemblies, one per line. They are relative to your checkout directory.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But do I have to write down each name of test in the box provided.. what if I have like 50 tests? Is there a Run all tests option ?

Comment: You can use wildcards (*.dll), or maybe use the "MSTest run configuration file". Don't know how to do the last thing (I use NUnit and wildcards), but that may be the way to go in that case